# Gaining access to the submit handler's event object in KnockoutJS

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I've bound my ViewModel's `submitForm` method to my `form` element as follows:

```
<form action="#" method="post" data-bind="submit: submitForm">
```

My ViewModel looks like the following:

```
function ViewModel() {
    this.submitForm = function (data, event) {
        console.log(event); //undefined
    };
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

When I submit my form, the handler above is fired, but `event` is `undefined`. I'm basing the above code on the [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html#note_2_accessing_the_event_object_or_passing_more_parameters) which states the following:

> **Note 2: Accessing the event object, or passing more parameters**
>
> In some scenarios, you may need to access the DOM event object
>   associated with your click event. Knockout will pass the event as the
>   second parameter to your function, as in this example:

```
<button data-bind="click: myFunction">
    Click me
</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var viewModel = {
        myFunction: function(data, event) {
            if (event.shiftKey) {
                //do something different when user has shift key down
            } else {
                //do normal action
            }
        }
    );
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
</script>
```

*Note: the syntax error above was copied verbatim from the KnockoutJS example. I assume it was a mistake on their end, and that the obvious correction should cause the code to work as documented.*

This code sample, and quote from the documentation, as best as I can tell, mimics what I wrote above. However, [as can be seen in this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X9CYX/), `event` is `undefined`.

### Question

- How can I gain access to the `event` object in my submit handler?

---

For those wondering why I referenced the `click` binding documentation, I was directed there from the [`submit` binding documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/submit-binding.html#notes) which states the following:

> For information about how to pass additional parameters to your submit
>   handler function, or how to control the this handle when invoking
>   functions that aren’t on your view model, see the notes relating to
>   the click binding. **All the notes on that page apply to submit handlers
>   too.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[In the current implementation](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/master/src/binding/defaultBindings/submit.js#L8) you **cannot** get the `event` object inside your `submit` binding handler.

However you can use the [`event` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/event-binding.html) and manually subscribe on the `submit` event:

```
<form method="post" action="#" data-bind="event: {'submit': submitForm}">
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MD4hg/).

Comment: Perfect. I find it odd that the `event` object isn't passed to the `submit` binding, but the `event` binding will work for my purposes as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

From [KnockoutJS submit documentation:](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/submit-binding.html)

> KO passes the form element as a parameter to your submit handler
>   function.

So, you may need to use the [The "event" binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/event-binding.html):

`data-bind="event: {submit: submitForm}"`

Comment: Yes but the docs also state: _"For information about how to pass additional parameters to your submit handler function, or how to control the this handle when invoking functions that aren’t on your view model, see the notes relating to the click binding. All the notes on that page apply to submit handlers too."_